# rails polymorphic association doesn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have model with polymorphic association.

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  #attributes target_id, target_type
  belongs_to :target, polymorphic: true
end
```

And Target model, which is user.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, as: :target
end
```

But method `@user = User.find params[:id]; @user.tags` returns `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>` while `Tag.where(target_id: @user.id, target_type: 'User')` returns some objects I except.

What's wrong?

Comment: don't you need to call user.target to get the tags? see : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: Try `user.last.tags` instead of `user.tags`

Comment: @NekoNova instance of ```Tag``` should have method ```target```, not ```User```

Comment: @SharvyAhmed I mean that ```user``` is instance of model ```User```, not class. Question is edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved!

I just add to model `foreign_key`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, as: :target,
                  foreign_key: target_id
end
```

Thanks everyone, who try to help.

Answer (score 0):

It's a wrong way because it gives error like `NameError: undefined local variable or method user for main:Object`, first you have to find user and  it's tags like:

`@user=User.find(1)`

`@user.tags`

Comment: I mean that ```user``` is the instance of ```User```, not class. Question is edited.

Answer (score 0):

From an instance of the `User` model, you can retrieve a collection of `tags` like this:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@user.tags
```

Similarly, if you have an instance of the `Tag` model, you can get to its parent:

```
@tag.target
```

Comment: ```@tag.target``` works, but ```@user.tags``` doesn't.